# How to abort a RESTBuilder connection

Tags: total.js

we need to abort this RESTBuilder call for various reasons

```
RESTBuilder.PUT(url)
    .file(file, CONF["fileDownloadDirectory"] + file)
    .callback( 
      function (err, res, output) {
         console.log(output.status);
      }
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `RESTBuilder` doesn't support aborting the request.

Comment: Can we expect this functionality update in future releases

Comment: Of course, I'm going to create a to-do for it.

Comment: To-Do list: https://trello.com/b/PeIWPLPG/framework